# Remove rows from dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I know this has to have been addressed before, but I cannot seem to find an answer that works

I have the columns that I want to test the condition against and I want to remove all rows where their value in any of the three columns is above a given value.

```
x  a  b  c  d  
1  2  1  3  4  
2  3  5  2  2  
3  3  3  3  2  
4  1  2  3  3
```

if I ran against this dataframe, with my cutoff value being anything greater than 3, then I should be returned with

```
x  a  b  c  d
3  3  3  3  2
4  1  2  3  3
```

Comment: "Any of the 3"? You have 5 columns. What columns are you testing on?

Answer (score 6):

If your dataframe is `df` then `df[~df[df>3].any(axis=1)]`

Comment: `df[~(df.gt(3)).any(1)]` is faster.

Comment: @ScottBoston nice. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove rows like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.loc[df.x>=3,:]
```

You can also use conditions using numpy logical_and and logical_or if you have upper and lower limit

```
df = df.loc[np.logical_and(dd.x<=3,df.x<=0),:]
```

You can also use ~

```
df.loc[~df.x.isin([1,2]),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
cols = ["a" , "b" , "c"]
greater_than_3 = (df[cols]>3).any(axis=1)
df = df[!greater_than_3]
```